scalar-to-scalar derivate with matrix involved
Given a matrix-to-scalar function $$f(\mu) = AB^H(\mu)CB(\mu)$$where $A\in \mathbb{C}^{N\times N}$, $C\in \mathbb{C}^{N\times N}$, and $B(\mu) \in \mathbb{C}^{N\times N}$ is a diagonal matrix with each diagonal element being a function related to a scalar $\mu$.
How can we calculate the derivate $$\frac{d \text{Tr}(f(\mu))}{d \mu}$$.
My initial attemp was to use the chain rule $$\frac{d \text{Tr}(f(\mu))}{d B(\mu)}\frac{d B(\mu)}{d \mu}$$. However, this approach is incorrect since the dimensions of these two resulting outputs do not match.

What's the $H$ exponent on $B$? Does it mean anything?

You should at some point compute the derivative in index notation and practice the mechanics of returning it to matrix notation after completing the calculation. But the end result of that process can also be quoted from a resource like the Matrix Cookbook after being massaged a bit.

@RicardoMM Here $H$ means the conjugate transpose of a matrix

$
\def\tr{\operatorname{Tr}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\rr#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\p{\partial}   \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
$Treating $\lbrace B,B^H\rbrace$ as formally independent variables yields
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= \tr(f) :=: \tr\LR{AB^HC,\rr{B}} :=: \tr\LR{CBA,\rr{B^H}} \
\grad{\phi}{\mu} &= \tr\LR{AB^HC;\rr{\grad{B}{\mu}}} + \tr\LR{CBA;\rr{\grad{B^H}{\mu}}} \
}$$
